# POJ 2136 Vertical Histogram

Tags: java

This is a poj problem - http://poj.org/problem?id=2136
I realize its an easy one but somehow the online judge is not accepting my solution though it seems to be working for me for the sample input. It says "wrong solution". I have made sure that there are no extra spaces and no extra lines as mentioned in the question. Could somebody please point out where am I going wrong ?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;
public class poj2136 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 0;
    TreeMap<Character,Integer> hm_frequency = new TreeMap<Character,Integer>();
    while(counter<4)
    {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String words[] = line.split(" ");
        for(String word: words)
        {
            //System.out.println(word);
            for(int i=0; i<word.length();i++)
            {
                char key = word.charAt(i);
                if((int)key>64 && (int)key<91)
                {
                    if(hm_frequency.containsKey(key))
                    {
                        hm_frequency.put(key,hm_frequency.get(key)+1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hm_frequency.put(key,1);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        counter++;
    }

    while(true)
    {           
        int max_value = maxvalue(hm_frequency);
        char ch = maximumchar(hm_frequency, max_value);
        if(max_value == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        Iterator iter = hm_frequency.keySet().iterator();
        int stop_flag = 0;
        while(iter.hasNext() && stop_flag==0)
        {
            char key = (Character) iter.next();
            if (key== ch)
            {
                stop_flag = 1;
            }
            if(hm_frequency.get(key)== max_value)
            {
                hm_frequency.put(key, max_value-1);
                if(stop_flag == 0)
                System.out.print("* ");
                else
                System.out.print("*");  
            }
            else
            {
                if(stop_flag == 0)
                System.out.print("  ");
                else
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }       
    Iterator iter = hm_frequency.keySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        char key = (Character) iter.next();
        if(iter.hasNext())
        System.out.print(key+" ");
        else
        System.out.print(key);
    }
}

public static char maximumchar(TreeMap<Character,Integer> hm_frequency, int max_value)
{
    Iterator iter = hm_frequency.keySet().iterator();
    char ch = '.';
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        char key = (Character) iter.next();
        int value = hm_frequency.get(key);
        if(value==max_value)
        {
            ch = key;
        }
    }
    return ch;
}

public static int maxvalue(TreeMap<Character,Integer> hm_frequency)
{
    Iterator iter = hm_frequency.keySet().iterator();
    int max = 0;
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        char key = (Character) iter.next();
        int value = hm_frequency.get(key);
        if(value>max)
        {
            max = value;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to output the full alphabet, and you are printing only the letters in your text:

> with the upper-case alphabet separated by spaces

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Would have taken me a lifetime to figure that one.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes a single fresh look on the problem could be the solver.